# How to auto scroll to target div if an id exists within body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider i have a full screen slider on my website, when clicking on navigation menus its really annoying to scroll down every time you visit a page or a refresh.

So lets Say i have a structure like:

```
<body page-section="news">

    <div class="royalslider">
        This is a slider and it is fullscreen
    </div>

    <div id="body-layouts">
        This is the body layout
    </div>

</body>
```

How do i go about auto scroll to **body-layouts** div if **page-section="news"** attribute exists within body?

More information: 
Visit this website http://unionstationdenver.com/ you will notice that when clicking on navigation's, you're automatically scrolled down to the targeted divs :)

Comment: Here's the script in charge of scrolling the page on the website you linked: http://unionstationdenver.com/lib/js/550.js

Comment: Maybe scrollIntoView does what you need ? If you want to drive it from javascript that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

With [js](/questions/tagged/js) vanilla:

```
// first you get the the value of page-section
var section = document.querySelector("body").hasAttribute("page-section");
// after you check the value
if(section == "news") {
// if it is ok, you redirect
    location.href = "#body-layouts";
}
```

With [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
var section = $("body").attr("page-section");
if(section == "news") {
    location.href = "#body-layouts";
}
```

With multiple attributes:

```
var attr1 = $("body").attr("page-section1");
var attr2 = $("body").attr("page-section2");
var redirection = "";
if(attr1 == "news") {
    redirection = "something";
} else if(attr2 == "something") {
    redirection = "something"; 
}

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $(redirection) ).offset().top - NAVBARHEIGHT
}, 0);
```

Comment: Hi! The Js code doesn't work, Im ok with jQuery tho, but however i would like to use more attributes instead only page-section, im not really good with javascript so help is highly appreciated :) and to add one more question: I would also want to add something like .top -65 when scrolled to the view because i have a sticky header and the targeted div goes beneath the header :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example of using `scrollTo` plugin to specific divs on the page using jQuery. ID is passed to function, replaced (`newsOneLink -> newsOne`) and then scrolls to the corresponding div, avoiding ID's that already exist. If you want to add more just make sure `Link` is appended at the end of the id only for the `<a>` tag.

```js
function goToByScroll(id){
        // Reove "Link" from the ID
        id = id.replace("Link", "");
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
            'slow');
    }

    //Change slow to a number to change the animation speed

    $("#links > a").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //Now go to function to scroll to div
        goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));           
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="container">
        <div id="links">   
                <a id = "newsOneLink" href="#">News One</a>
                <a id = "newsTwoLink" href="#">News Two</a>
                <a id = "newsThreeLink" href="#">News Three</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="newsOne">
                <p class="header">News One</p>
                <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>       
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>           
            <div class="sections"id="newsTwo">
                <p class = "header">News Two</p>
                <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>   
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div class="sections" id="newsThree">
                <p class = "header">News Three</p>
                <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are okay with jQuery I would suggest the following to run when the document is ready. This will work with an offset modification or not.

```
$(function() {
    function scrollTo(hash, offset) {
        if(typeof offset === 'undefined') {
            offset = 0;
        }
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + hash).offset().top + offset }, 'slow');
        return false;
    }
    var section = $("body").attr("page-section");
    if(section && section === "news") {
        scrollTo("body-layouts");
        // scrollTo("body-layouts", -65);
    }
});
```